# R Error when I use mice::pool function: "Error: No tidy method for objects of class lmerMod"

Tags: r, r-mice

On my linux server, I want to use `mice::pool` to combine results obtained from multiple `lmer` fits with multiply imputed data. However, I get this error:

> Error: No tidy method for objects of class lmerMod

However, if I run the code on my local system, the error disappears.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide sample data using `dput` and R code.

Comment: have you loaded the `broom.mixed` package?

Comment: Thanks! The problem is solved by loading broom.mixed package!

Comment: Thank you so much!